# Node JS returned value is undefined

Tags: node.js, getjson

```
var ide = req.params.brand_id;
gmpro_model.aggregate(
        {$match: {brand_id: ide}},
        {$group: {total_gross:{$sum : "$Gross"}}}
    ,function(err, results){
    console.log(results);
});
```

please help me figure out the problem with this one, it returns an undefined value. I am new to `Node JS`. Thank you

Comment: Have u tried to console.log the err?

Comment: Please, provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I already tried console.log, i found out that total gross has already have a value but does not perform $sum operation

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/

Answer (score 1):

from MongoDb $group menual [MongoDb $group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#group-aggregation)

> The _id field is mandatory; however, you can specify an _id value of null to calculate accumulated values for all the input documents as a whole.

try this

```
   var ide = req.params.brand_id;
    gmpro_model.aggregate(
        {$match: {brand_id: ide}},
        {$group: {_id:null,total_gross:{$sum : "$Gross"}}}
    ,function(err, results){
    console.log(results);
    });
```

Comment: this lines seems to run smoothly but cannot perform $sum

Comment: then check the documentation

Comment: It was the same mistake made by me before few months :-)
@AfrazAhmad